# how to create redis key from php user input?

Tags: php, redis, key

i had successfully connected redis key server to php in ubuntu 12.10.my code like below.

```
<?php
$redis = new Redis();
$redis->connect('127.0.0.1',6379);//connection`
$list=fopen("php://stdin","r");
$gg=fgets($list);
$key=$gg; //apply redis key
?>
```

i tried to create redis key from php user input but that cant create.how to create key from php user input or by $_POST or $_GET method or any different way to create redis key.thanks in advance

Comment: What are you going to do with this key?

Comment: i tried to use redis server instead of mysql with php.to store information in redis key from user.

Answer (score 2):

It is simple either you can create the Hash for it or simple Key value pair like below

```
<?php
$redis = new Redis();
$redis->connect('127.0.0.1',6379);//connection`
$list=fopen("php://stdin","r");
$gg=fgets($list);
$redis->set($gg,'value you want to set') //apply redis key //Method 1
$redis->Hset('hashname',$gg,'value you want to set') //apply redis key//Method 2
```

To get the data you need to follow the below method

```
  $redis->get($gg)//Method 1
  $redis->Hget('hashname',$gg) //apply redis key//Method 2

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

i tried,solved it.i hope this post may be helpfull to others.

```
<?php
$redis = new Redis();
$redis->connect('127.0.0.1',6379);//connection`
$list=fopen("php://stdin","r");//get user input
$gg=fgets($list);//store in $gg
$key=redis->set($gg,"value"); //apply redis key
?>
```